# Annotation DB has no 'select' method in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, bioconductor

I have the following code in R:

```
require(hgu133a.db)

entrezIDs <- select(hgu133a.db, probeNames, "ENTREZID")
```

where `probeNames` is a list of strings corresponding to probes found in this database.

I am attempting to translate it to Python using rpy2:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
hgu133a_db = importr('hgu133a.db')

entrez_ids = hgu133a_db.select(hgu133a_db, probe_names, 'ENTREZID')
```

But receive the error:

> AttributeError: module 'hgu133a.db' has no attribute 'select'

I've searched the documentation (`?select`) and as far as I can tell the database **hgu133a.db** inherits a `select` method from the **AnnotationDbi** class.

How do I properly resolve the library where `select()` is coming from, so I can use it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[should have been a comment to @merv 's answer, but exceeded the number characters]

`rpy2`'s `importr()` is trying to help a being specific about which package namespace an R object is coming from, while R's common usage is much less so (and can lead to annoyances such as the loading order of R packages having an influence on which one of the functions with the same name is executed).

The tradeoff with `importr` is that one has to know where an R symbol is coming from. There is a less-known function in `rpy2` that can help finding where a given R symbol is defined(*): https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html#finding-where-an-r-symbol-is-coming-from .

Otherwise, one can also use `r()` to retrieve the object that would be picked(*) in an R session.

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r('select')
```

(*: as mentioned earlier, the order in which R packages were loaded earlier in the session can have an influence on which R object is picked).

Comment: Using `select = r('select')` after importing the R libraries works perfect!  Much better solution than tracking down the abstract base class manually.

Comment: May be not better in every situation. It can certainly be more convenient when wanting to "just run what R would run" but the use of namespaces created by `importr` can be helpful to write more robust code (by not letting which R packages were imported in R, or in which order they were, potentially change the function called).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two issues with the above.  First, **AnnotationDbi** should be used to resolve the `select()` method.  Second, `hgu133a_db` is an **InstallSTPackage** object - instead one must use `hgu133a_db.hgu133a_db`.  Putting it together, the translation from R to Python is:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

annotation_dbi = importr('AnnotationDbi')
hgu133a_db = importr('hgu133a.db')

entrez_ids = annotation_dbi.select(hgu133a_db.hgu133a_db, probe_names, 'ENTREZID')
```